# Pattern from String

Tags: java, regex, logging

i want to extract pattern from a string for ex:

```
string x== "1234567 - israel.ekpo@massivelogdata.net cc55ZZ35 1789 Hello Grok";
pattern its should generate is = "%{EMAIL:username} %{USERNAME:password} %{INT:yearOfBirth}"
```

basically i want to create patter for logs generated in the java application. any idea how to do that ?

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want a pattern to extract parts of log entries? In your x I can identify the mail-address, but what part of x should be password or yearOfBirth?

Answer (score 0):

In past i've do some with reguar expression, but in my case the string having ever the same composition pattern or order. 
I this case, you can done 3 matching pattern and make the find operation 3 times in order of pattern.

If not so, you must use an text analyzer or search tool.

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to use [grow library](https://github.com/aicer/grok) to extract data from logs.

### Example:

```
public final class GrokStage {

  private static final void displayResults(final Map<String, String> results) {
    if (results != null) {
      for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : results.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue());
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    final String rawDataLine1 = "1234567 - israel.ekpo@massivelogdata.net cc55ZZ35 1789 Hello Grok";

    final String expression = "%{EMAIL:username} %{USERNAME:password} %{INT:yearOfBirth}";

    final GrokDictionary dictionary = new GrokDictionary();

    // Load the built-in dictionaries
    dictionary.addBuiltInDictionaries();

    // Resolve all expressions loaded
    dictionary.bind();

    // Take a look at how many expressions have been loaded
    System.out.println("Dictionary Size: " + dictionary.getDictionarySize());

    Grok compiledPattern = dictionary.compileExpression(expression);

    displayResults(compiledPattern.extractNamedGroups(rawDataLine1));
  }
}
```

Output:

```
username=israel.ekpo@massivelogdata.net
password=cc55ZZ35
yearOfBirth=1789
```

Note:

This are the patterns used before:

- EMAIL `%{\S+}@%{\b\w+\b}\.%{[a-zA-Z]+}`
- USERNAME `[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+`
- INT `(?:[+-]?(?:[0-9]+))`

More info about grok-patterns: [BuiltInDictionary.java](https://github.com/aicer/grok/blob/master/src/main/resources/grok_built_in_patterns/grok-patterns)